# Is there a PHP function to turn a month number into a localised name?

Tags: php, class

Is there a PHP function to turn month numbers into localised month names?

My current solution is as follows, but I feel there is a better way.

```
class num2month {
    static function month($num){
        $m = array(1=>"Январь",
                    2=>"Февраль",
                    3=>"Март",
                    4=>"Апрель",
                    5=>"Май",
                    6=>"Июнь",
                    7=>"Июль",
                    8=>"Август",
                    9=>"Сентябрь",
                    10=>"Октябрь",
                    11=>"Ноябрь",
                    12=>"Декабрь");
        return $m[$num];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup... This seems to be good.

Comment: Yeah ok .. but might not work for multiple language ....

Comment: @user2062756 I believe you have instantiated that class and called the method and echoed the return value, right? Just writing the class and the function won't run it, you have to call it.

Comment: Sure, I'm callin it with num2month::month($var)

Comment: Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, date('Y')));
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:
$m = 1;
$month = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 10));

$month == "January", but you still need to provide some translating array or table in database to translate to needed language.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working just fine. See this php fiddle (click on run) http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6v6-iuz

```
<?php
$test = new num2month;
$test->month(3);
class num2month {
    function month($num) {
        $m = array(1=>"Январь",
                    2=>"Февраль",
                    3=>"Март",
                    4=>"Апрель",
                    5=>"Май",
                    6=>"Июнь",
                    7=>"Июль",
                    8=>"Август",
                    9=>"Сентябрь",
                    10=>"Октябрь",
                    11=>"Ноябрь",
                    12=>"Декабрь");
        echo $m[$num];
    }
}
?>
```